# [ODOO15]Execute a JavaScript script when a page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo

I'm working on a JavaScript script that aims to add some events on a couple of buttons in the barcode interface in Odoo V15.

When I'm trying to add an event on a button in the standard navbar at the top of the page (the navbar that allows, for example, to go back to the applications list) I can't locate the button with jQuery. I select the button through its class, but the returned object remains empty.I'm simply doing something like :

```
console.log($('.buttonClass'));
```

I guess that is because my script executes before the button generation.
I tried to place my script at the last position of the assets in the manifest, but it still not working.

**How could I execute JavaScript code only when my page is fully loaded, so I can be sure that all of my elements exist?**

Thank you,
Regards,

Comment: I think you're looking for the `defer` attribute. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: this is not the Odoo way of loading widget.. so probably you need to define your widget first.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `DOMContentLoaded` event for all your script.

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Example:

```js
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  // your code
  console.log($('.buttonClass'));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using `$(document).ready()`?

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($('.buttonClass'));
});
```

See more about `ready` on [jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).